# MySQL Index questions, simple query takes too long for a relatively small amount of indexes rows on a medium-large table

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing

I have a relatively large table (5,208,387 rows, 400mb data/670mb index),
all columns i use to search with are indexes.
`name` and `type` are VARCHAR(255) BTREE INDEX
and `sdate` is an INTEGER column containing timestamps.

I fail to understand some issues,
first this query is very slow (5sec):

```
SELECT *
FROM `mytable`
WHERE `name`  LIKE 'hello%my%big%text%thing%'
AND `type` LIKE '%'
ORDER BY `sdate` DESC LIMIT 3
```

EXPLAIN for the above:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE      mytable range   name        name    257 NULL    5191    Using where
```

while this one is very fast (5msec):

```
SELECT *
FROM `mytable`
WHERE `name`  LIKE 'hello.my%big%text%thing%'
AND `type` LIKE '%'
ORDER BY `sdate` DESC LIMIT 3
```

EXPLAIN for the above:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE      mytable range   name        name    257 NULL    204 Using where
```

the amount of rows scanned different makes sense because of the indexes,
but having 5k of indexed rows take 5 seconds seems way too much.

also, ordering by `name` instead of `sdate` makes the queries very fast, but I need to order by the timestamp.

Second thing I do not understand is that before 
adding the last column to the index,
the db had index of 1.4GB,
not after running an OPTIMIZE/REPAIR the size is just 670MB.

Comment: The `%` wildcard always adds time to your query, and the more you have in your LIKE predicate the longer it will take.

Comment: i know, and i know that it takes more rows, but even the index to all "Hello%" is just 5k rows, and shouldn't take 5 seconds (it takes 70 seconds for some other queries)

Comment: How many records match `'hello%'`?  How many match `'hello.my%'`?  I suspect therein lies your answer.  Many more records can be eliminated from the latter query before one needs to commence pattern matching.

Comment: Why do you need this? "AND `type` LIKE '%'"

Comment: Like I said, "hello%" matches 5k rows and "hello.my%" matches just 204. yes its a big difference, but this is not reasonable timing.
type LIKE '%' is part of a different set of code I did not discuss here (was tested, made no change)

Comment: Seems like the problem is that MySQL does the ordering before the index is used. Making the ORDER BY part of an outer query is good, but is there a prettier way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, only the portion *before* the first `%` can take advantage of the index, the rest of the `like` strings needs to process all rows which match `hello%` or `hello.my%` without the help of one. Also, ordering by another column then the index used, probably requires a second pass, or at least a scan rather then an already sorted index. Options to better performance (can be implemented independently from each other) are:

1. Using a full-text index on the name column and using a `MATCH() AGAINST()` search rather then `LIKE` with `%`'s.
2. Adding the `sdate` to in index `combined (name,sdate)` could very well speed up sorting.

Comment: Like I wrote before, I understand that only hello%/Hello.my% are used for indexing, but 5k rows at 5-70 seconds is way too slow.
This wasn't as slow when just `name` was indexed (same exact query).
Why would full-text index be better? Every change to the db takes for ever so I guess I'm just being cautious

Comment: If you search for `%a%sequence%of%words`, but the order doesn't really matter: the full-text index (1) breaks up the whole text in individual words and (2) indexes those, so efficiently, if we disregard the minimum-length limit of a word (usually 4), that is looking up 4 words in an index rather then scanning a full table for 1 column. And more speed... well, it helps if you have the whole table in memory (but you cannot force that easily, you'll just have to fiddle with server-wide settings). If order _does_ matter, or you are searching for parts of words, don't go for the fulltext index.

Comment: Seems like the problem is that the `sdate` column is ordered before the indexes are used. using this SELECT * FROM ( SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE `name`  LIKE 'ghost%rider%spirit%bdr%spar%' LIMIT 3) AS a1 ORDER BY `sdate` DESC; did the trick. Any less ugly way to do it?

Comment: Hm, you could try some [index hints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/index-hints.html), ignoring `sdate`.

Comment: Adding a "FORCE" on `name` makes it very fast. The outer query has the same speed. first is prettier, last is more efficient. Any other ideas? Seems like I'm getting close to the optimal solution.